# How to change redirect controller after login with ADFS ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, adfs, ws-federation

I am performing federated authentication in an ASP.NET MVC application, for which I use the following configuration code

```
public class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        // Para obtener más información sobre cómo configurar la aplicación, visite https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=316888
        ConfigureAuth(app);
    }

    public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(
        new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationType = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType
        });
        app.UseWsFederationAuthentication(
        new WsFederationAuthenticationOptions
        {
            MetadataAddress = "https://example.com/FederationMetadata/2007-06/FederationMetadata.xml",
            Wtrealm = "https://example.com/appId",
        });

        app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
    }
}
```

AccountController

```
public class AccountController : Controller
{
    public void SignIn()
    {
        if (!Request.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.Challenge(new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = "/" }, 
                WsFederationAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
        }
    }

    public void SignOut()
    {
        string callbackUrl = Url.Action("SignOutCallback", "Account", routeValues: null, protocol: Request.Url.Scheme);

        HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.SignOut(
            new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = callbackUrl },
            WsFederationAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType, CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
    }

    public ActionResult SignOutCallback()
    {
        if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            // Redirigir a la página principal si el usuario está autenticado.
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Inicio");
        }

        return View();
    }
}
```

The login is successful, but, what I want to do is that at the moment of logging in, go to another controller, for example: Home / Main.

The problem is that I don't understand how the mvc project works with federated authentication, how it knows what action or controller it should go to after logging in, since no configuration of that is done.

**How can I change or configure the controller to go to after the successful login?**

Comment: Isn't the controller just based on the URL? So website/Account will be calling the AccountController. Set the RedirectUri of the SignIn function to website/Home or use Response.Redirect("website/Home")

Comment: Or you can simply do a `return RedirectToAction("Main", "Home ");` once you successfully authenticate a user in your `SignIn` method.

Comment: Did you get this resolved?

Comment: @RahulSharma no, reading about it, I found that you can change the url after logging in the configuration of the relying party trust, but no more